# Php str_replace not working with special chars

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, internationalization

why isn't this working as expected:

```
 echo str_replace("Ã©","é","FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
```

result:

```
"FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football"
```

i'm expecting to have:

```
"Fédération Camerounaise de Football"
```

Comment: The problem here is character encoding, not `str_replace()`...

Comment: @Cobra_Fast ok and what shoud i do ?

Comment: I think this is a multibyte issue, in which case try using either [`mb_ereg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php) or [`mb_ereg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-eregi-replace.php).

Comment: Set up your stuff properly (I'm suspecting you're having a UTF-8 database connection and ISO-8859/latin output) or mess around with `utf8_decode()`, `mb_convert_encoding()` or `iconv()`.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast i don't use any database, it's a one line code:  echo str_replace("Ã©","é","FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football");

Comment: @RachidO. Then why don't you just write the proper string in there in the first place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. This string is not incorrect and in need of replacement, it is simply encoded with UTF-8.

All you have to do is `utf8_decode('FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football')`.

## Update:

You are seeing `FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football` as output because you are double passing your data in UTF-8.

Observe:

**file1.php saved in UTF-8 format:**

```
<?php
    echo "Fédération Camerounaise de Football";
```

Output:

> > FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football

Now, if you tell the browser you are using UTF-8, it should display the content straight:

**file2.php saved in UTF-8 format:**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    echo "Fédération Camerounaise de Football";
```

Output:

> > Fédération Camerounaise de Football

Perfect.

Howover, you are doing things even worse. You have an UTF-8 encoded string, and is encoding it again, by writing it to a UTF-8 encoded file.

**file3.php saved in UTF-8 format:**

```
<?php
    echo "FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football";
```

Output:

> > FÃƒÂ©dÃƒÂ©ration Camerounaise de Football

What a mess. Let's make it worse by seeing if we can fix this with `str_replace`:

**file4.php saved in UTF-8 format:**

```
<?php
    echo str_replace("Ã©","é","FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
```

Output:

> > FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football

As you can see, we "fixed" it. Sort of. **Thats what you are doing.** You are transforming `ÃƒÂ©` into `Ã©`,  even though you are not seeing this because your editor won't let you see the real symbols behind the encoding, **but the browser does**.

Let's try this again with ASCII:

**file5.php saved in ASCII format:**

```
<?php
    echo str_replace("Ã©","é","FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
```

Output:

> > Fédération Camerounaise de Football

Magic! The browser got everything right now. But whats the real solution? Well. If you have a string hardcoded in your PHP file, then you should simply write `Fédération Camerounaise de Football` instead of placing the god damn thing wrong. But if you are fetching it from another file or a database, you should take one of the two courses:

1. Use `utf8_decode()` to transform the data you fetch into your desired output.
2. Don't transform anything and use `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` to tell the browser you are printing content in UTF-8 format, so it will display things correctly.

Comment: str_replace("Ã©","é",utf8_decode('FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football')) not working

Comment: No dude. Don't use `str_replace` at all!

Comment: You are probably making things worse if you are hardcoding the string in your PHP file like this. The file itself is probably also encoded in UTF-8, so nothing of this will work. Save it in ASCII if you want to see what is really going on here.

Comment: If you are using PHP to generate HTML you should stick with UTF-8 and send `<meta charset="utf-8">` with your HTML headers instead. Just remember **you simply don't need any "fix" for this string if you do so**.

Answer (score 2):

//edit after comment

`FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football` is an `UTF-8` encoded string so i don't know what input is not `utf-8` encoded in your document but you have two options.

1. your input that are passed to `str_replace` is `utf-8` but the characters that you have used in the functions to replace are `ANSII` or something else => not work - this means your document is not `utf-8` - this is why `uft8_decode` works 
   `str_replace(ANSII, ANSII, CONVERT_TO_ANSII(UTF-8))`
2. your input is not `utf-8` and your document is - so this would work
   `str_replace(UTF-8, UTF-8, CONVERT_TO_UTF-8(ANSII))`

---

`str_replace` works great with multibyte characters - your problem is not the function its is because you try to replace different encoding types. instead of using a alternative function - i suggest you to fix the input that are passed to `str_replace` to `utf-8` and make sure that your document is `utf-8` encoded too.

if your source only support non `utf-8` encoding use `utf8_encode` to convert your input to `utf-8`

http://php.net/manual/de/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: @RachidO. i explained my answer

Comment: str_replace("Ã©","é",utf8_encode('FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football')) and the result is "FÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â©dÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â©ration Camerounaise de Football"

Comment: Dude, your string is simply encoded twice, just use `echo utf8_decode(utf8_decode('FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football'));` you will see it.

Comment: @Havenard can you make it as an answer so i can accept it ?

Answer (score -3):

Check The following Code:

```
$chain="FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football";
$pattern = array("'Ã©'");
$replace = array('é'); 
$chain = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $chain);
echo $chain;
```

Comment: it gives me "FAdAration Camerounaise de Football"

Comment: What is your expected result?